# Ember JS: observed properties on destroyed objects

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working on a simple app which displays a list of issues of a particular repo on Github. Below is the code of IssueView which generates the html of an issue and insert to the DOM

```
 App.IssueView = Ember.View.extend({
   tagName: "li",
   classNames: ["sugar", "issue_wrapper"],
   templateName: "app/templates/issue",
   init: function() {
     App.LabelsController.addObserver("label", this, this.labelUpdated);
     this._super();
   },
   click: function(event) {
     var target = event.target;

     if (target.className == "title") {
       // Using bindingContext is a temporary solution to access data of this issue
       App.IssuesController.set("issue", this.bindingContext);
       App.IssuesController.set("state", "viewIssueDetails").notifyPropertyChange("state");
     }
   },
   labelUpdated: function() {
     this.labels = this.labels || this._collectLabels(),
     label = App.LabelsController.get("label").name;

     this.set("isVisible", this.labels.indexOf(label) != -1);
   },
   _collectLabels: function() {
     var labels = [];

     this.bindingContext.labels.forEach(function(label) { labels.push(label.name) });

     return labels;
   }
 })
```

The way I generate it is

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#view App.IssuesListView}}
    {{#each App.IssuesController}}
      {{view App.IssueView contentBinding="this"}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

The problem I had is with this line

```
App.LabelsController.addObserver("label", this, this.labelUpdated);
```

Everytime a new IssueView is generated and inserted into the DOM, I got an error "You cannot set observed properties on destroyed objects" when the 'label' property of LabelsController is updated. When I look into Firebug I saw that my IssueView's state is "destroy" instead of inDOM. I wonder why that happened and what can I do to get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#each` helper in your template will ensure that IssueViews are created and destroyed as the collection of issues changes. You are manually adding the observer, which means you are responsible for removing the observer, too. I believe that using the `observes(...)` function prototype extension will handle that for you. (See http://ember-docs.herokuapp.com/symbols/Ember.Observable.html under "Observing Property Changes").

If you want to pursue the manual route, consider moving the addObserver to `didInsertElement` and adding a corresponding removeObserver in `willDestroyElement`.

*One side note: if I'm understanding what you are trying to do with this code correctly, I would consider binding to an ArrayController that handles presenting the correct set of issues based on the selected label instead of the approach you are taking.*

Comment: That is great. I went with the manual approach and called 'removeObserver' in 'willDestroyElement' and it seems to be working now.

Comment: And about your side note, that's exactly what I'm doing here. Basically, when 'labelUpdated' is called, each 'issueView' will ask itself: 'Hey, is the label that the user picks one of my labels?', if not the view will be hidden and vice versa

Comment: Glad it worked. The alternative design I'm proposing in the side note is when the label is updated, an array controller (e.g. `App.FilteredIssuesController`) would update it's content array to add/remove the appropriate issues. Your template `#each` would be bound to the `FilteredIssuesController` and would automatically update when the controller's content array changed. It would mean less code and more separation of model and view concerns. Just my $.02. :)